# Transpose a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Mysql and I want count distinct value and then make the distinct values as the column name.

I have a table Students like this

```
  ID Names Age
  1   Tim  12
  2 James  14
  3 White  13
  4  John  13
  5 Annie  11
  6  Judy  13
```

I want to find how many people in each age. My **expected result** is:

```
11 12 13 14
1  1  3   1
```

I tried the query: `"Select count(age), age from Students group by age;"`

It gives out:

```
  count(age) age
          1  11
          1  12
          3  13
          1  14
```

How can I take a "transpose" to the table?

Comment: You should do this at the application level.

Comment: Search for existing Q&A on pivoting data in SQL.

Comment: Yea, I don't understand the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `MySQL` you will need to know age in advance:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN (age='11') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (age='12') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (age='13') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 13,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (age='14') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 14
FROM 
    Students
```

Comment: what if attribute age is a string? Is it the same?

Comment: You also may automate table transformation, have a look at this article - http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/#automating

Comment: @ITDONG _"if attribute age is a string"_, then you should fix the data-type. You only create difficulties for yourself when attributes are stored using the wrong types.